# Is there a way to decolorize Safari 12 pinned tab icons?

Tags: safari

Safari 12's pinned tabs now show garish, distracting, and unpredictable colored icons in place of the subdued grayscale icons of previous versions. Is there a way to decolorize these icons?

Comment: You can turn the icons off. Though I imagine you knew that and are looking for a different solution — just commenting this in case someone else might be happy with this solution.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist No actually I didn't know that. Where's that setting?

Comment: Not on the laptop at the moment, so I’ll have to double check later, but I believe there’s a checkbox you can untick under Preferences > Tabs. Something about website icons.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist No that's not it. That shows icons on all regular tabs. I want to decolorize the icons on the pinned tabs.

Comment: Whoops — missed the word pinned. Sorry!

Comment: It would be great if this was an option for all tabs but it's currently not possible. Perhaps someone will build an extension for it.

Comment: @Andrew If extensions ever work with 12!

Comment: Extensions work with Safari 12 just fine, as long as they're new model.  Only a surprise to developers not paying attention.  Sadly, there are lots of those.

Comment: I'm subscribing to this comment chain given how I miss the feature, safari just upgraded and it's what I would define a finger in the eye.

Comment: @cedivad Finger in the eye is right. Frustratingly, when a Safari looses focus, the icons look exactly like we want!

Comment: This isn't going to help you in the short term, but [it's possible for web developers to specify the color](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/pinnedTabs/pinnedTabs.html).  That never used to be the case (it was always gray), so it's going to take a while to catch on, but it should at least look a little less ugly just in time for Apple to ditch the whole concept and implement some crazy new favicon replacement.

Comment: Now, this is just an idea, but I'm pretty sure you could whip up a Tampermonkey script to override that value on every website that supplies a mask icon.  It won't work for sites that don't specify a mask, though.

Comment: @Zenexer Safari is already pretty unstable. I'm reluctant to mess with it. I think I'll just move everything over to Chrome. Most of what's worth preserving will migrate to Lunix and everything else (calendar, messaging, photos, mail, office apps, collaboration; even spellcheck) is better with Google.

Answer (score 1):

The app Faviconographer hacked favicons onto Safari tab prior to the feature officially rolling out.

https://timingapp.com/faviconographer/

It would likely be fairly straightforward to modify the app to re-grayscale the icons.

> If you have a legitimate interest in the source code, contact me.

Try asking the dev for the feature, or for the source code and build it yourself.